# How to use the installCaCert method from DevicePolicyManger API?

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I tried to install silently a .p12 certificate, I installed a signed apk in order to have system app priviles but it doesn't work.

```
final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("cert.p12");
byte keychain[] = new byte[(int) fileInputStream.available()];
fileInputStream.read(keychain);

DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
if(! dpm.installCaCert(getComponentName(),keychain))
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"installCaCert  Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The toast shows "installCaCert Failed"

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution or the cause of the failure?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to be a device/profile owner or your app should have been delegated to perform the task on behalf.
2. You took a PKCS12 file which is a user certificate store. You might want to extract only the CA certificate from the chain and install that .crt or .cer file.

Comment: How my app can be delegated ?

My goal is to use the api, So Yes I should extract only the CA certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Your same code is working for me,
the only differences I have are:

- I'm installing a .pem certificate
- My app has system privileges

Comment: how did you gave system privileges to your app

Comment: You must include your app into the OS or be delegated from the device constructor.